# E-commerce cart div container to close when clicked outside of the container

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, cart

I'm working on a e-commerce site where I have this shop cart. The cart container opens and closes when clicked on a cart button from navbar, or when clicked on the X from the cart container. I want to make this cart container to close when the user click outside of the cart container and I assume I'm using the right JS code.....but when I try it the cart won't open at all! I guess because the cart button is not contained in the cart container somehow.....

```
<!-- PREVIEW CART START -->
      <section class="cart-container">
        <i class="fas fa-times" id="cart-close"></i>
        <p class="cart-title">Coșul tău</p>
        <div class="cart-content">
          <div class="empty__cart">
            <p>Nu aveți produse în coș.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <div class="cart__total">Total</div>
          <div class="cart__price">0 Lei</div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn--larger cart-btn" id="cart__btn">Cumpără</button>
      </section>
    <!-- PREVIEW CART END -->
```

```
.cart-container {
  background: var(--color-bg);
  position: fixed;
  top: 8rem;
  right: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  border: var(--border);
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 1000;
}


.cart-container__active {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 90vh;
}
```

I applied the "most used" type of code for this action, but won't work as expected.....no errors on the console....just the button to open the cart won't work anymore....I can't open the cart container at all. If you need further information I will provide it. Please help!
Thanks!

```
// CART PREVIEW AND TRASH BUTTONS START

let cartBtn = document.querySelector("#cart");
let closeCart = document.querySelector("#cart-close");
let cartBox = document.querySelector(".cart-container");

cartBtn.onclick = () => {
  cartBox.classList.toggle("cart-container__active");
  return false;
};

document.addEventListener("click", function clickOutside(e) {
  let clickSpot = e.target;
  if (!cartBox.contains(clickSpot)) {
    cartBox.style.display = "none";
  }
});

closeCart.onclick = () => {
  cartBox.classList.remove("cart-container__active");
};

// CART PREVIEW AND TRASH BUTTONS END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the problem is here `let cartBtn = document.querySelector("#cart");` Maybe it should be `let cartBtn = document.querySelector("#cart__btn");`